# Swap escaped characters

Tags: java, escaping

I'm trying to swap the parentheses in the String `A * (B + C) / D`, but swapping them, results in `A * \)B + C( / D` instead of `A * )B + C( / D`.

```
public class InfixToPrefixExpression {
        private String swapStrings(String expression, String one, String two){
    
            return Arrays.stream(expression.split(one, -1))
                         .map(s -> s.replaceAll(two, one))
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(two));
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String expression = "A * (B + C) / D";
            String result = new InfixToPrefixExpression().swapStrings(expression,
                             "\\(","\\)");
            System.out.println(result);
        }
}
```

How do I remove the extra back-slash that appears in the resulting string? I tried the following as well, but the String.join() method adds the extra slash in the result.

```
//        String[] split = expression.split(one, -1);
//        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
//            split[i] = split[i].replaceAll(two, one);
//        }
//        String result = String.join(two, split);
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy method of swapping may be to swap `"("` for a special character like `"_"`, then swap `")"` for `"("` and finally `"_"` for `")"` like this:

```
    final String expression = "A * (B + C) / D";
    final String result = expression
            .replace("(", "_")
            .replace(")", "(")
            .replace("_", ")");
```

If you don't want to use a special character, you can do a trick with splitting the expression by one bracket like this:

```
    final String expression = "A * (B + C) / D";

    final String[] substrings = expression.split("\\(");
    final List<String> replacedSubstrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String substring : substrings) {
        replacedSubstrings.add(substring.replace(")","("));
    }

    final String result = String.join(")", replacedSubstrings);
```

Comment: Thank You. I'm wondering why is it not required to escape the braces in the `substring.replace()` or `String.join()` functions? I'm obviously missing a subtle point here.

Comment: The argument of String#split is a regex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and in regex, the bracket has a special meaning, so you have to escape it. You also have to escape the escape character, so Java will not interpret `\(` as a special character. On the other hand String#replace takes a CharSequence as the arguments, so don't need any escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to provide special values to be used in regular expressions and in `Collectors.joining`:

```java
private static String swapStrings(String expression, String one, String two){

    String reOne = "\\" + one;
    String reTwo = "\\" + two;

    return Arrays.stream(expression.split(reOne, -1))
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll(reTwo, one))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(two));
}
```

Then this method may be called without escaping parentheses:

```java
String expression = "A * (B + C) / D";
String result = swapStrings(expression, "(",")");

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
A * )B + C( / D
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the behavior change when calling the function with escaped braces -  swapStrings(expression, "\\(","\\)")? Intellij also complains about "Illegal/Unsupported Escape sequence" when I use the modified code, however it compiles successfully.

Comment: Hi, the error about "Illegal/unsupported escape sequence" in `"\("` is obvious, there's a limited set of characters used as [escape sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html): `` \n \t \r \b \f \' \" \\ ``.  **The IntelliJ _warning_** occurs because this IDE checks that the string is going to be used in a regular expression (argument to `split`), which _may be_ incorrect if \\ is not escaped properly.  While IDE "cannot" see that we're going to escape _another_ character.  That is, if you replace with code `String reOne = "\\(";` this warning is gone.

Comment: My bad, there were two questions there: 1. Why was the behavior different when the original code was doing essentially the same thing. (Think the copied the code in my earlier comment got messed up)? 2. Intellij complains about the statement `String reOne = "\\" + one;` although it compiles OK.

Comment: 1. In regexp (as in `split`), parentheses MUST be escaped and extra \\ is consumed by the regexp engine; in plain string (String.join / Collectors.joining), the parentheses do NOT need to be escaped, and \\ is not consumed - that's why you had extra \\ in original code.  2. IntelliJ has its own feature to check for possible issues with _regexp_, while Java compiler does not care for this.